# Selection on PostGIS layers is... randomly working in QGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, qgis-3, select

## Context

Quick question...
Since the last minor update of [QGIS](https://www.qgis.org) 3, I cannot select features anymore on *some* (not all) [PostGIS](http://postgis.net/) layers (see Fig.1).

[image: QGIS Screenshot]

Fig.1: *On the left table, the selection is not working, but on the right it is.

Both are PostGIS layers from the same server (localhost), and both attribute tables have the option "Move Selection to Top" enabled (not shown on the image)*.

Using either the "DB Manager" or the "Data Source Manager | PostgreSQL"  doesn't change this behaviour.

Both are plain PostgreSQL tables, not views.

On the left layer, If I click a feature in the attribute table itself, it gets selected a few pico-seconds, then the blue background saying it's selected turns back to white. But... If I zoom to feature I have "ghostly" selected, the main screen in centered on this actual feature.

## Question

Is the problem known, do I have to tweak something either inside QGIS or [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/)?

### Environment

Ubuntu: 18.04
QGIS: 3.12.2-București, compile against Qt 5.9.5
PostgreSQL: 10.12
PostGIS: 2.4

Comment: is it a view by chance?

Comment: No, it's a plain table.

Comment: does selecting from the table works? If yes, is the proper geometry then selected, or is it a random one?

Comment: Partially. It seems buggy, see update. The "Zoom map to the selected row" is effectively going to the feature, but it's neither with a blue background in the attribute table, nor a yellow main color on the map as selected features normally do.

Comment: check if the proper field for "feature id" is set (when adding the layer) and that there is no duplicates in this field (in the DB)

Comment: Actually the "Feature ID" field is [empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88Rwt.png) while adding the layer with the Data Source Manager. But the PostgreSQL table actually does have an "id" field, which was defined as; `id INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY`. So it is definitely unique.